# What are the consequences of disabling nmi_watchdog?

Tags: battery, watchdog, optimization

My aim was to improve battery life for my laptop.

I have already applied some advised modifications like enabling ALPM, and adding `pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1` at grub startup of my system.

Besides,
I happened to read (on a former page of the ubuntu wiki -I think so), an advise saying to switch `nmi_watchdog` permantently off.

But what is the consequence of disabling `nmi_watchdog` for my system ? Is it really any good , or is it a micro optimisation ? What is the tradeoff ?

Comment: I believe the answer is: if your system hangs, the kernel won't panic. So basically, it's good for almost nothing unless you're debugging kernel or have some kind of mission-critical stuff that has to happen before the machine shuts down.